# Why am I getting "The request to create a scratch org failed with error code: C-1033" when trying to create a scratch org?

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org

When I try and create a scratch org as follows...

`sfdx force:org:create -s -f config/project-scratch-def.json -a myscratchorg`

...I get the following error message:

> The request to create a scratch org failed with error code: C-1033

I have googled for an answer and see that this has been an issue before around previous releases, but I can't see any workaround.

Is it just a case of waiting for an update?

**Edit**

*Scratch Org Definition*

```
{
  "orgName": "company",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "features": ["EnableSetPasswordInApi"],
  "settings": {
    "lightningExperienceSettings": {
      "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
    },
    "mobileSettings": {
      "enableS1EncryptedStoragePref2": false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you also include your scratch org definition file?

Comment: @Swetha - I've added the scratch org definition file. Thanks.

Comment: Seeing this error message again for the past two days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by adding:

```
{
    ...
    "release": "previous",
    ...
}
```

to the `project-scratch-def.json` file.

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file.htm) for the `release` property name says:

> Same Salesforce release as the Dev Hub org. Options are preview or previous. Can use only during Salesforce release transition periods.

My Dev Hub org has just been upgraded to winter '23, so possibly it is in the  "release transition period". However, setting the `release` property to "preview" did *not* work and resulted in an error message of:

> The request to create a scratch org failed with error code: VR-0003.

Comment: Sprint 23' is scheduled for today for my org, seems they have some issues as they canceled it midway. I was only able to create a scratch org by setting the "release" key to "preview". before then "release" wasn't even mentioned in the scratch-def.json field.